# Horizontal slider disappears when using constraints in Xcode Swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift3

I have a horizontal slider that appears and works fine. But when I add any constraint, it disappears from the build. I've also done an archive and tried it on my real iPhone 5c device.

Any ideas what could be causing this and how to fix it?

Screen in Xcode, showing constraints:

[image: screen in Xcode]

Screen in preview (same on real device), and it does not appear:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you haven't set the y position of the slider view. You need to hook that up too, that should fix it.

On the left side of the storyboard, there is the overview of your ViewControllers. In the upper right hand corner of the one, you're currently in, there should be a tiny warning symbol:

[image: missing constraints example]

If you click on it, you will be presented with what might be the issue:

[image: missing constraint suggestions]

Comment: I agree with @LinusGeffarth, you don't really want to see the red box outline in your storyboard/XiB files, it is telling you your constraints are not set correctly(The appearance will be different at run time)

Comment: That was it! Wasn't aware of this warning symbol. That fixed the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help :) @podcastfan88